# When you define a read function for a kernel module, where does the function's arguments come when it is called?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Let's say I have a kernel module named "hello".

For example:

```
static struct file_operations hello_fops = {
        .open = hello_open,
        .read = hello_read,
        .release = hello_release,
};
```

```
static ssize_t hello_read(struct file *f, char *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offset){
       // some code here
}
```

When you read from the `/dev/hello` character device file, the `hello_read` function will be called, but where do the function's arguments come from?

Comment: Parameters `buf` and `len` comes from the [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) system call. `f` parameter denotes previously opened file descriptor, and `offset` - current file position, stored for that file descriptor.

Comment: `offset` might not be a pointer to the current stored file position. For the [pread](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) system call, it will be a pointer to a temporary variable set to the passed in offset.

Comment: The `struct file` pointed to by `f` is the kernel representation of an "open file description" (although in the `.open` file operation handler, it is only potentially open, with its fate determined by the return value). Each process has a table that maps file descriptors (of type `int`) to `struct file *`. A reference counting mechanism ensures that the `.release` handler is not called until the original file descriptor and all the duplicated and inherited file descriptors have been closed.